# How to enable editing table cell data on multiple rows?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I enable data editing inside a table cell with javascript on multiple row.
I have written a code that gets the cell data and replace it with a text box that has previous data on it and saves the data in to the cell after you finished editing. But I want to make it possible with multiple table rows. Btw. the table will be Php generated.

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>EDIT USER</title>
    <script>
        function edit() {
            var a = document.getElementById("fname").innerHTML;
            var b = document.getElementById("lname").innerHTML;
            document.getElementById("fname").innerHTML='<input id="fnamefld" type="text" value="'+a+'"'+' />';
            document.getElementById("lname").innerHTML='<input id="lnamefld" type="text" value="'+b+'"'+' />';
            document.getElementById("edit_btn").disabled=true;
            document.getElementById("done_btn").disabled=false;
        }
        function done() {
            document.getElementById("done_btn").disabled=true;
            document.getElementById("edit_btn").disabled=false;
            var a = document.getElementById("fnamefld").value
            var b = document.getElementById("lnamefld").value
            document.getElementById("fname").innerHTML=a;
            document.getElementById("lname").innerHTML=b;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="0">
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Edit?/Done?</th>
        <tr>
            <td id="fname">User fname</td>
            <td id="lname">User lname</td>
            <td>
                <button id="edit_btn" onclick="edit()">Edit!</button>
                <button id="done_btn" onclick="done()">Done!</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <script> document.getElementById("done_btn").disabled=true;</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean with multiple rows? So you copy the textbox to every cell in a row?

Comment: First, you can stay the textbox in edit mode as locked and no-borders etc.  If not, Why you don't stay both the text box and label and toggle show/hide them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used this plugin in the past and found it incredibly useful

http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/